# Disable Ubuntu lock screen

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to disable the lock screen in Ubuntu Netbook Remix?

I don't want to enter my password every time I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about you go to the Screensaver preferences (right-click on desktop, etc) and uncheck the lock-screen option? (I think there is one there).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Ubuntu logo in the left hand upper corner.

Click Office > All Applications > Screensaver.

Uncheck **lock screen when screensaver is active** then click close.

Answer (score 0):

It is a screensaver preference. While in the screensaver settings uncheck the "lock screen when screensaver is active" this may not disable the lock screen when you boot up though. Looking into that.

http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com